# select from grouped collection

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table (`HallPlan`) with fields:

```
Row, Seat, Width, Height, X, Y
```

And grouped collection by `Y`:

```
var ordered = hallPlans.GroupBy(s => s.Y).OrderBy(o => o.Key);
```

now I want to select max X from all minimum X for each group. For example `ordered` contains three groups, we have:

```
first group contains 3 records with X coordinates: 15, 50, 80;
second group contains: 16, 50,80;
and last group contains: 15, 40, 60;
```

select all min from each groupes: `15, 16, 15`
and select max from the above: `16`.

How can I do this with LINQ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Min` and `Max` functions.

```
class HallPlan { public int X { get; set; } }

...

var groups = new[]{
                    new []{new HallPlan{X=15},new HallPlan{X=50},new HallPlan{X=80}},
                    new []{new HallPlan{X=16},new HallPlan{X=50},new HallPlan{X=80}},
                    new []{new HallPlan{X=15},new HallPlan{X=40},new HallPlan{X=60}}
                };

var maxmin = groups.Select(g => g.Min(h => h.X)).Max(); // result is 16
```

`groups.Select(g => g.Min(h => h.X))` will select the minimun `HallPlan.X` from each group, and `.Max()` will then return the biggest value of those.

Answer (score 1):

```
var allMinX = ordered.Select(g => g.Min(s => s.X));
var minMax  = allMinX.Max();
```